# Trouble to get near by ATM list

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am using Google Map API to get the Latitudes and Longitude of near By ATM. I have get Google API key by my Google credentials. I am requesting by my app with Code

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search     /json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", currentCentre.latitude, currentCentre.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currenDist], googleType, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

and I am getting

```
{
    "debug_info" =     (
    );
    "html_attributions" =     (
    );
    results =     (
    );
    status = "REQUEST_DENIED";
} as response.
```

please let me know what to do??

Comment: First remove unneccessary white space in your url.

Comment: There are not spaces lie in my Code,these are appearing here only...I am getting response too...but the status is "REQUEST_DENIED", yet I have API key and already enabled the place API and Google MAP in API Access section..

Comment: can you post your final url?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the Google Place API for getting the ATM location look for the link below

[How to get 20+ result from Google Places API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614258/how-to-get-20-result-from-google-places-api)

Comment: I am using in same way. I am using the API key make the request format properly. I have enable all access permission required with my Google credentials but not getting status = "REQUEST_DENIED" in response.