# Get all places around 2 kilometers using Google's PlaceDetectionApi

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using following API to get all places from current location,

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
        .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
        Log.v("App",
                "2. likelyPlaces.getCount() : "
                        + likelyPlaces.getCount() + ", placeType : "
                        + placeType);
        places.clear();
        GooglePlace place;
        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {                                          
                    place = new GooglePlace();
                    place.setAddress(placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                            .getAddress());
                    place.setId(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getId());
                    place.setLatLng(placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                            .getLatLng());
                    place.setName(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName());
                    place.setPhoneNumber(placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                            .getPhoneNumber());
                    place.setPriceLevel(placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                            .getPriceLevel());
                    place.setRating(placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                            .getRating());
                    places.add(place);
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        likelyPlaces.release();
    }
});
```

This one returns only 20 places, and also no photo of the place. So I want to know how to get all places around 2 kilometers from current location. Also how to get the place image.

I know we can get more than 20 results by using

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=Enter Latitude,Enter Longitude&radius=10000&types=store&hasNextPage=true&nextPage()=true&sensor=false&key=enter google_map_key &pagetoken="Enter the first page token Value"

But for this API we have to provide **Server IP** for get API key. So need to know how can we get more than 20 results by using

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
        .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
```

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you found answer already but you should check this out if not:

> The Places API will return up to 20 establishments per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627664/3677394