# How to get only a specific attribute using Google place API

Tags: android, rest, google-places-api

Well i'm coding now an android app , and i use the Google place REST Api  on it to get information about some place , the problem is when there is so many results in 
the Response of the Http-request does not contain all the Json file , only some objects and the last object is not complete , so i want to reduce the data that comes from the API response , and i ask if there any PARAMETER to SET in the URL to do this for me  .

Not : the URL = (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=H%C3%B4pital+New York&sensor=false&key=API_KEY_HERE )

Comment: You can do this easily, there are many query parameters to get the consolidated records as much as satisfy the query, use radius=500, types=food and many more. I suggest to read the google places API from [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)

Comment: @jitainsharma : Well i searched before asking , but can't find any thing that match with my needs , i think you don't get my question and i don't need to do a filter because i already do it , but i want to remove some informations that back to me to reduce the String result ...

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is pagetoken:

```
public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
            throws Exception {

        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?"));
            request.getUrl().put("key", YOUR_API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("location", latitude + "," + longitude);
            request.getUrl().put("radius", radius); 
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
            request.getUrl().put("types", types);

            PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);

            if(list.next_page_token!=null || list.next_page_token!=""){
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                         /*Since the token can be used after a short time it has been  generated*/
                request.getUrl().put("pagetoken",list.next_page_token);
                PlacesList temp = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
                list.results.addAll(temp.results);

            }
            return list;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Referenced from: [Google Places API : Number of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255523/google-places-api-number-of-results)